# CustomVision Classification in Docker container: Cannot feed value of shape

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I have created a classification model in CustomVision and exported it to a Dockerfile (Linux). The model works fine when testing it from inside CustomVision GUI, but when connecting to the docker container and calling it like

```
curl -X POST http://127.0.0.1/image -F imageData=@some_file_name.jpg
```

I always get a error like

> "Error: Could not preprocess image for prediction. Cannot feed value of shape (1, 227, 227, 3) for Tensor 'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 224, 224, 3)'"

This is even when some_file_name.jpg is one of the files the model was trained from...

An observation: Models we created in August'18 and exported to Dockerfiles works fine. When modifying these models now (e.g. removing a file from the trainingdata) and rebuilding the model, it fails like noted above. The zip file created when exporting the model is nearly double in size now compared to in August. No configuration has been changed and the model is still build on the same datacenter.

Any tips/help is most appreciated.

Comment: Is export to Dockerfile actually working at the moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app folder of the export there's a file predict.py. Change the line,

network_input_size = 227
to 
network_input_size = 224

I then rebuilt and reran my docker container and it worked.